# Вернуть данные из функции

Tags: javascript

Как извлечь массив данных arrMyLatLng из функции.

```
db.transaction(queryDB, errorCB);

  function queryDB(tx) 
{ 
tx.executeSql('SELECT * FROM Attractions', [], querySuccess, errorCB);
}

   function querySuccess(tx, results) 
  {
 var arrMyLatLng = [];
 var len = results.rows.length;
 var arrLatitude=[], arrLongitude=[];
 for (var i=0; i<len; i++)
 {
    arrLatitude[i] =  results.rows.item(i).latitude;
    arrLongitude[i] = results.rows.item(i).longitude;
    arrMyLatLng[i] = new google.maps.LatLng(arrLatitude[i], arrLongitude[i]);
 }

return  arrMyLatLng  ; // Необходим данный массив, чтобы манипулировать данными из него уже за пределами этой функции. 
}
```

Спасибо.

Comment: callback это делается и только.

Comment: Так у вас функция возвращает уже arrMyLatLng, о каком извлечении вы говорите?

Comment: callback это параметр для функции (либо переменная/функция в родидельской области видимости) который содержит функцию вызываемой после текущей вместо return соответсвенно

my_callback(arrMyLatLng);

Comment: Т.е. вы предлагаете любой следующий код, для которого необходим arrMyLatLng помещать в тело функции querySuccess?

Comment: аккуратно если завернуть, то это не так уж и страшно,

Comment: функция querySuccess вызывается бесконечное число раз(т.к. постоянно запрашиваются координаты). Получается функции, которые будут внутри нее, тоже будут постоянно повторяться. Как решить эту проблему?

Comment: создать callback функции столько раз сколько нужно (не думаю что больше 3х) и передавать их как параметр для queryDB, который в свою очередь будет передавать их querySuccess, как передавать параметр я уже показал в предыдущем ответе

Comment: Передать количество повторений  для callback?